# ion-header-bar not working with sidemenu and slidebox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is a link of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgd7Z/1/

The project uses ionicframework and angular(basically none yet) to create a simple swiping/sidemenu app. There are two pages that the user can swipe between with a header/navbar, then all of this moves over for the sidemenu.

I am attempting to use `<ion-header-bar>` in place of the `<ion-nav-bar>` so it will move with the sidemenu, but the  buttons and text do not line up correctly. Am I missing some class on the buttons? I tried wrapping them all in on div with `class="buttons"` after checking the inspector, but that didn't work either.

Is the way that I am using the common method for a nav-bar that is going to be moved by the sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgd7Z/2/)

you needed to use `<ion-header-bar type="bar-dark">` not `<ion-header-bar="bar-dark">`

Comment: This is exactly it! I thought that looked weird, but thats what I get for reading the docs in the middle of the night!

Comment: type= needs to be changed to class= in order for the css to work (coloring and text centering for the bar).